# Should you ask questions you already know the answer to?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I want to ask a question that I already know the answer to, and I think it is a very good life hack. If the questions would help others and we already know the answer should we answer ourselves or should we wait for someone else to answer it?

Comment: :( You didn't answer your own question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## [Yes,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking) [it's](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) [encouraged!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

So long as the question is on topic for Lifehacks and it fulfills all of our question requirements, please do so! There's even a button for posting your own answer along with the question below the content section of a new question.

Asking questions that you answer yourself fulfills the purpose of the site - to build a knowledge base and provide solutions - quite well. It also gives others to provide their own ways of solving the problem you bring up.

Comment: And you also get a nifty award for answering your own question then marking another answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score -3):

In the question we have to mention something we have already tried and why it is not successful or if it is successful then why we are not satisfied with it. At the same time we are encouraged to give answers to our own questions. This is confusing for me. You ask the question and know the answer, but need to think of another answer which is not satisfactory in the same situation. This is not logical and rational. Something should be done about this.

Comment: No longer true -- see http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/1256/59 (especially Robert's answer there). However, the question should still be a high-quality question.

Comment: @Shokhet from this link I understand that I can ask questions without including "what I have tried" and then give my own  answer  like [this one](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/123/%CE%97ow-can-i-keep-my-jeans-zippers-from-opening-on-their-own)

Comment: There are currently four reopen votes on that question, including mine.

Comment: Is it better if we wait some time before choosing our own answer as best answer?

Comment: You don't actually have a choice -- the system won't let you accept your own answer for two days after asking.